# Is it possible for ArcGIS Portal to modify security settings of the source zip file?

Tags: arcgis-portal

**Is it possible that during the upload of a zipped file geodatabase to ArcGIS Portal, that portal is able to change the security settings of the source zip file?**

To walk through an example.
I have an existing Hosted Feature Service that is published and shared to different groups on ArcGIS Portal. I created this from a zipped File geodatabase.
The data needs updating.
So I use the 'Overwrite' tool inside of ArcGIS Portal admin site.
After I select the correct zipped filegeodatabase, the process runs for just under a minute and the hosted service is now back up and running with the latest data.

BUT

The source zip file - which was taken from a file share on a server, has had its security properties changed, so much so that even the Owner of the zip file is no longer myself (even though I created the file literally 5 mins before). I cannot delete the file or move it and its completely locked out from myself.

I'm at a complete loss to understand how ArcGIS Portal would modify the security settings as part of an upload.

I have experienced this 3 time now, but - I cannot successfully replicate the issue at will, so hence the question.

**Is this even possible that ArcGIS Portal has the ability to change the source file security permissions as part of an Overwrite action?**

Some additional details regarding Process Monitoring. I ran ProcessMonitor whilst uploading a zip file to ArcGIS Portal. This upload went successfully. the Process Operation that i was looking for, was a 'FileSystemControl' operation. However this process never occured on the zip file (which kinda makes sense, because the zip file permissions haven't changed).
So my only guess is that - its possible this operation only occurs when the actual 'error' is occurring.

Comment: You're saying the zipped file, on *disk* is having its security settings changed. You aren't talking about security settings for an item in the portal, right? If this is the case, my initial take is: *no*. The web browser is facilitating the file upload to ArcGIS Portal, not sure how anything in that process would modify the file on disk.

Comment: ArcGIS Enterprise components run with the permissions of the server process. If asked to write a file in a certain location, it might have access to clobber your path.

Comment: Yes just confirming its the zip file on disk that is having its permissions changed.

Comment: I think you'd need to do something like run Process Monitor to watch the file and see if you can capture what software is making the changes. Try these steps: https://support.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=136